# Проблемы настройки .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Столкнулся с проблемой настройки .htaccess для сайта

У меня есть файлы и директории с одинаковым названием (например /folder и folder.html)

При включении RewriteEngine On (убираю .html из ссылок) получаю ошибку 403 там, где имена файла и папки совпадают...

Access forbidden!

"You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected."

Сейчас файл .htaccess у меня выглядит так:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Что можно сделать в данной ситуации?

Заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Папки не будут обрабатываться регуляркой

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

тут подробней http://habrahabr.ru/post/140693/